# It's possible to prevent CS8602 (variable may be null) as the package owner

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nullreferenceexception, compiler-warnings

For example I have xUnit test

```
var record = _context.Records.Where(x => x.Foo == FooValue).FirstOrDefault();

// This check WILL NOT prevent the warning from being displayed
Assert.NotNull(record);

// This check WILL prevent the warning from being displayed
if (record == null) throw new Exception(); 

// Warning CS8602 "record may be null here"
Assert.True(record.Foo == FooValue);
```

It's possible from the owner of the package (in general) to somehow instruct the compiler that the output of the method is compliant to warning CS8602? I use several packages and I see warnings that are not relevant and I don't want to place

```
#pragma warning disable CS8602 // Dereference of a possibly null reference.
#pragma warning restore CS8602 // Dereference of a possibly null reference.
```

everywhere. If it's possible I would fix this at least in the packages I own.

Comment: Use this Assert.True(record!.Foo == FooValue);

Comment: Why aren't you using `_context.Records.Where(x => x.Foo == FooValue).First();` in that example?

Comment: You can add [several attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing thank you, I will try `[return: NotNull]` it might do the trick :-)

Comment: @Amir I did not know [null forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) thank you!

Comment: @MatthewWatson you are right, but I wanted to demonstrate the issue so there can be any other method returning value or null.

Comment: If you want to assert that the value returned from a method YOU are calling is not null, just put a `!` at the end of the call: `var record = _context.Records.Where(x => x.Foo == FooValue).FirstOrDefault()!;`

Comment: If you want to assert that the value returned from a method that you are implementing and you are using Nulllable enabled, just make sure you don't put a `?` at the end of the method declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to resolve nullable warning you can use ! in c#

check this :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings

For Example:
Assert.True(record.Foo! == FooValue);